# can someone post a "multiple table" example yadcf

Tags: yadcf

I'm trying to get the "multiple tables" example from https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf working and i cant seem to get it to work.

Was wondering if anyone could post a zip file of a working example that i could just tweak.

I have a specific outcome i'm trying to test for with multiple tables where the second table gets filtered by the contents of the first table.

example: http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/dom_multi_columns_tables_1.10.html

Answer (score -4):

You can grab all the needed files from the [yadcf-showcase repo'](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf-showcase) , here is the link to the [zip of the showcase](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf-showcase/archive/master.zip) , and this is the [relevant html](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf-showcase/blob/master/war/dom_multi_columns_tables_1.10.html) , here its in action in the [showcase](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/dom_multi_columns_tables_1.10.html)

you can grab the [war](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf-showcase/tree/master/war) folder and place it into your *\Public* folder of the DropBox and access it via the "Copy public link* that way there will be no need in web server.

Comment: this comment was downvoted because it doesn't provide an answer to the question, just links. Please use the comments feature for answers like these in the future.

Comment: @StephanMuller, the question was about how to get an offline copy of the relevant files for tweaking them, my answer provides links to the resources with instruction about how to setup them for that tweaking... so what all that "just links" about?